# what if the container of priority_queue doesn't have push_back function

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

`std::priority_queue::push`

Inserts a new element in the `priority_queue`. The content of this new element is initialized to val.

This member function effectively calls the member function `push_back` of the underlying container object, and then reorders it to its location in the heap by calling the `push_heap` algorithm on the range that includes all the elements of the container.

Now when we make our own `priority_queu` and specify a `container` which is `not in C++ STL` and that does not have a `push_back` function then how will the `std::priority_queue::push` work...?

Comment: It won't work. Although the *"not in the C++ STL"* part is irrelevant.

Comment: all STL containers have the function named as push_back..

Comment: No, they don't. But that's beside the point. What I'm saying is that it doesn't matter whether or not the container is part of the STL (or even the C++ standard library). All that matters is that it implements the appropriate functions.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley can u give me an example of a `Container` from `STL` which doesnt have a push_back function..

Comment: 23.6.4/1 [priority.queue] - Any sequence container with random access iterator and supporting operations front(), **push_back()** and pop_back() can be used to instantiate priority_queue. There's more but you should get the point. Read it, live it, learn it. Bottom line...it **won't** work.

Comment: map/set/multimap/multiset. And if you actually mean the C++ standard library, rather than STL, there's also the unordered variants, and `std::forward_list` and `std::array`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Container` that you template `std::priority_queue` on has to satisfy the `SequenceContainer` requirements and provide `front()`, `push_back()` and `pop_back()`. Without them, the code will simply not compile, just the way the following code with fail to compile.

```
template <typename T>
class Fail
{
public:
Fail() {a.make();}

private:
T a;
};

int main()
{
Fail<int> fail_int;
return 0;
}
```